# What is the domain and range of this relation in?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

From: Triamudom Add.math sheet pg.19

[image: work]

This is the progress I’ve done so far. As you can see I couldn’t find a way to arrange $x$ in terms of $y $ or vice versa which is required to solve for the domain and range.

Comment: I think you can solve both ways the trionym. There should be not only one function.

Comment: See conics for reference.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank you. I do know that writing the problem with MathJax is a more favorable way to improve search and answering experience but, due to limitations of my memory and working from a portable phone at the time of emulating the question, I just couldn’t use MathJax as an viable option of emulating the problem itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you work on it
$$y=\dfrac{x\pm\sqrt{192-3x^2}}{2}$$
then you will get$$(x,y)\le 8$$
Now,you decide.